# Countdown timer for use in several places at same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, e-commerce, countdown

I want to make a countdown timer, that can be used on several places in the same page - so I think it should be a function in some way.

I really want it to be made with jQuery, but I cant quite make it happen with my code. I have e.g. 10 products in a page, that I need to make a countdown timer - when the timer is at 0 I need it to hide the product.

My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".product").each(function(){

        $(function(){
            var t1 = new Date()
            var t2 = new Date()
            var dif = t1.getTime() - t2.getTime()

            var Seconds_from_T1_to_T2 = dif / 1000;
            var Seconds_Between_Dates = Math.abs(Seconds_from_T1_to_T2);

            var count = Seconds_Between_dates;
            var elm = $(this).attr('id');
            alert(elm);
            countdown = setInterval(function(){
                $(elm + " .time_left").html(count + " seconds remaining!");
                if (count == 0) {
                    $(this).css('display','none');
                }
                count--;
            }, 1000);
        });
    });
});
```

EDIT 1:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".product").each(function(){
            var elm = $(this).attr('id');           

        $(function(){
            var t1 = new Date()
            var t2 = new Date()
            var dif = t1.getTime() - t2.getTime()

            var Seconds_from_T1_to_T2 = dif / 1000;
            var Seconds_Between_Dates = Math.abs(Seconds_from_T1_to_T2);

            var count = Seconds_Between_dates;

            alert(elm);
            countdown = setInterval(function(){
                $(elm + " .time_left").html(count + " seconds remaining!");
                if (count == 0) {
                    $(this).css('display','none');
                }
                count--;
            }, 1000);
        });
    });
});
```

Do you have any solutions to this?

Comment: Why do you navigate to google when a count is down to zero, when you actuall wanted to remove the product?

Comment: Bergi: It is a dummy code I have used for that part. 2 sek :-)

Comment: The whole.. I think the each is my problem.. And then the countdown function doesn't seem to be as quick as supposed - it should somehow be a better script, when I maybe have 100+ countdowns on the same page :)

Comment: I have now tested the "each" function with alert("Test"); and it seems to work. So it probably is the function inside, that needs some work. But how can I make it dynamical, so it works on every product?

Comment: It should do, doesn't it? Your `countdown` variable is global, but that shouldn't matter. Only your selector for the `.time_left` elements won't work like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably use a single interval function that checks all the products. Something like this:

```
$(function() {

    /* set when a product should expire.
       hardcoded to 5 seconds from now for demonstration
       but this could be different for each product. */
    $('.product').each(function() {
        $(this).data('expires', (new Date()).getTime() + 5000);
    });

    var countdown_id = setInterval(function() {
        var now = (new Date()).getTime();
        $('.product').each(function() {
            var expires = $(this).data('expires');
            if (expires) {
                var seconds_remaining = Math.round((expires-now)/1000);
                if (seconds_remaining > 0) {
                    $('.time-left', this).text(seconds_remaining);
                }
                else {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

You could also cancel the interval function when there is nothing left to expire.

Comment: That works with the 5 seconds - but how do I then make the counter update live? i have a div with class="counter", that should get updated every second and I have different dates on every product (dynamical) from database - but can't see how I can adapt your script to that? :/

Comment: I don't know what templating language you're using, but using the dates from the database could go like: {% for product in products %} $('#product-{{ product.id }}').data('expires', {{ product.expires }}); {% endfor %}

Comment: The counter div could be updated in the setInterval callback too. Is there just one? Then do $('div.counter').text(now) before the each().

Comment: Couldn't i save it like this:
<input type="hidden" name="hidden-{id}" id="time-{id}" value="{date}" />
And then get that with jQuery for the count down? :-)

Comment: You could. Then rather than the "expires = $(this).data(...)" you'd do "expires = $('time-' + $(this).attr('id')).val()".

Comment: Using data vs inputs? I like data, but they are similar: you either are generating javascript in your template or are generating html using your list of products. You could also inline the date in the product elems (<div class="product" expires="{ date }">). Or do you mean the format for the date? I'd use the same epoch time in seconds that is being used in the javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be that `this` doesn't refer to the current DOM element (from the `each`), but to `window` - from `setTimeout`.

Apart from that, you have an unnecessary domReady wrapper, forgot the `#` on your id selector, should use cached references and never rely on the timing of `setInterval`, which can be quite drifting. Use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".product").each(function(){
        var end = new Date(/* from something */),
            toUpdate = $(".time_left", this);
            prod = $(this);
        countDown();

        function countdown() {
            var cur = new Date(),
                left = end - cur;
            if (left <= 0) {
                prod.remove(); // or .hide() or whatever
                return;
            }
            var sec = Math.ceil(left / 1000);
            toUpdate.text(sec + " seconds remaining!"); // don't use .html()
            setTimeout(countdown, left % 1000);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: So I should get the id from outside the function?

Comment: Gave it a try (see Edit 1) - but doesn't seem to work though. It is not updating the time in the div. :)

Comment: I know what you think about the date - but there can be 10 different dates in the document - but this gives only opportunity of one? Is it possible to make it a function, that can have a dynamical date?

Comment: There is an own ("private") `end` variable for `each` element in the `.products` collection… - just like in your original script.

Comment: Yeah, but this is set to get the information from a database? How would I put the date into the javascript, when the script is not a part of my loop?

Comment: It is part of the `each` loop? I don't know how you got the `t1` variable in the first place, I expected that to be a dummy code, too?